# safely turn a data.table back into a data.frame

Tags: r, data.table

What's the safest way to get rid of/remove the `data.table` class from an object, turning it back into a data.frame?

I ask because I'm using script that relies on the following code:

```
newcol.index <- ncol(my.data) +1
my.data[,newcol.index] <- 3
colnames(my.data)[newcol.index] <- "test"
```

The `data.table` packages apparently does not like this, but it work fines using objects of class `data.frame`.

Comment: this doesn't even work on a data.frame.  `DF <- data.frame(a=1:2,b=1:2); colnames(DF)[3] <- 'z'` gives the error *Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("a", "b", "hello")) : 
  'names' attribute [3] must be the same length as the vector [2]*

Comment: Edited the post to describe exactly what wasn't working in `data.table`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `as.data.frame` method for data.tables is presumably the safest function to use. (Try typing `getAnywhere("as.data.frame.data.table")` to see exactly what it does.)

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(a=1:4, b=letters[c(1,1,2,2)], key="a")

class(as.data.frame(DT))  ## OR:  as(X, "data.frame")
# [1] "data.frame"
```

Comment: These days we have `setDF`

Comment: @user5359531 -- Unlike my proposed solution, `setDF()` changes the class of an object in place. To see it in action, run the first two lines of code in my answer and then do `class(DT); setDF(DT); class(DT)`.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien I wonder if it's worth updating the body of your answer, given that times have changed?

Answer (score 4):

If you are willing to convert your script to data.table, you can use use `:=` to assign by reference, this will automatically assign to the `(ncol(youdata)+1)th` column, and you can pass a character vector of the names to the LHS of the function. It will assign by reference,  so no copying!

```
DT <- data.table(a = 1, b = 2)

DT[,'test' := 3]


DT
   a b test
1: 1 2    3
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of how to convert from **data.table** to **data frame**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

df <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 6:10, c = LETTERS[5:9])
class(df)
#[1] "data.frame"

df <- data.table(df)
class(df)
#[1] "data.table" "data.frame"

class(df) <- class(as.data.frame(df))
class(df)
#[1] "data.frame"
```