# Subsetting columns works on data.frame but not on data.table

Tags: r, data.table, multiple-columns, subset

I can select a few columns from a `data.frame`:

```
> z[c("events","users")]
     events  users
1  26246016 201816
2    942767 158793
3  29211295 137205
4  30797086 124314
```

but not from a `data.table`:

```
> best[c("events","users")]
Starting binary search ...Error in `[.data.table`(best, c("events", "users")) : 
  typeof x.pixel_id (integer) != typeof i.V1 (character)
Calls: [ -> [.data.table
```

What do I do?
Is there a better way than to [turn the `data.table` back into a `data.frame`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13811572/safely-turn-a-data-table-back-into-a-data-frame)?

Comment: column subsetting should be done in `j`, not in `i`. `DT[, c("x", "y"), with=FALSE]`. Have a look at the 4th slide [here](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/CologneR_2013.pdf)

Comment: @Arun: thanks - please turn the comment into an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: sds, have done. Feel free to turn my comments into answers, if appropriate, for the future.

Comment: @sds Please also read the [data.table FAQ](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-faq.pdf). The first few FAQs cover this.

Comment: I will repeat something I have said many times before. Implicity is a bitch. Just like sometimes `mydf[, 1, drop = FALSE` comes mighty handy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Column subsetting should be done in `j`, not in `i`. Do instead:

```
DT[, c("x", "y")]
```

Check [this presentation](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/CologneR_2013.pdf) (slide 4) to get an idea of how to read a `data.table` syntax (more like SQL). That'll help convince you that it makes more sense for providing columns in `j` - equivalent of SELECT in SQL.

Answer (score 6):

Given that you're looking for a `data.table` back you should use `list` rather than `c` in the `j` part of the call.

```
z[, list(events,users)]    # first comma is important
```

Note that you don't need the quotes around the column names.